# Wrong output by for loop

Tags: list, dart

I am using a variable j which am incrementing everytime a for loop executes to count the no of loops it ran and adding the value of i in list a and then adding the list a to b but on printing b it is printing wrong output.

**My Code:-**

```
void main() {
  var a=[];
  var b=[];
  int j=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    j++;
    a.add(i);
    if(j>=4)
    {
      b.addAll(a);
      print(b);
    }
  }
}
```

Logically it should print [0,1,2,3,4] but it is printing:-

[0, 1, 2, 3]

[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: This is a very serious algorithm. I have not yet gotten to such complex algorithms. It's almost like a neural network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it is printing it twice and the second time with the same list duplicated is because of your logic of `j>=4`. It is getting hit twice. If you only want it to get it once then you'll need to remove the `=`

```dart
void main() {
  var a=[];
  var b=[];
  int j=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    j++;
    a.add(i);
    if(j>4)
    {
      b.addAll(a);
      print(b);
    }
  }
}
```

this happens because you are referencing `j` instead of `i`. `j` will hit 5, therefore your logic `j>=4` applies to 4 and 5, whereas `i` will not because it will only get up to 4.